# Error while creating SQLite database: "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near(9598)"?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a SQLite database in android and getting this error

```
"android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near(9598)."
```

on this line:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT)");
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: I think it would help to create a separate string of that sql command and print the string.. maybe if you edit the question and add that too will help us a bit more to solve the issue :)

Comment: please post the whole code of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the table already exist? Rather use ...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

and add a `;`:

```
... + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT);");
```

Comment: No, the table doesnt already exist, and i added what you said, but still the error comes, but the near(9598) is changed to near(12542) now!

Comment: Are you sure that all your variables (`KEY_ID`, `KEY_PH_NO`, ...) contain a valid column/table name? - and no column twice? I know, it sounds like a silly question, however, there is basiclly nothing else wrong with your Statement. Opened a *writable* database?

Comment: My TABLE_CONTACTS string had spaces in it, replaced them with _ and the error went away. Thanks!

Comment: Well allthough that wasnt the issue with existing table still your post solved the problem, as promised +1.

Answer (score 0):

try keeping KEY_ID is

```
private static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Trying your creation statement ([SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/7670d)) showing its actually ok, and since non of the exceptions defined in the [subclasses of SQLiteException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html) is thrown lets me think its something during building the statement, as the documentation states:

> **SQLiteException**
>
> A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL **parsing**
> or **execution**.

So i would try to separate the both steps, 1st build the statement in a string (including output to make sure how it looks like) then try to execute it.